Unity problem trying to build for Android
I'm trying to integrate IronSource/LevelPlay to my unity application.
I've upgraded to the latest unity LTS version :
Gradle keeps failing miserably to do so, can anybody help please ?:
stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJavaResource'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
4 files found with path 'commonMain/default/manifest' from inputs:
- C:\Development\FalloutSurvival\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\libs\co.touchlab.stately-concurrency-2.0.5.jar
- C:\Development\FalloutSurvival\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\libs\co.touchlab.stately-strict-2.0.5.jar
- C:\Development\FalloutSurvival\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\libs\io.insert-koin.koin-annotations-1.3.0.jar
- C:\Development\FalloutSurvival\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\libs\io.insert-koin.koin-core-3.5.3.jar
Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
for more information


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 3s
]

I am not the only one it seems : https://forum.unity.com/threads/gradle-build-keeps-failing-after-installing-ironsource-levelplay-package.1547348/

Any idea what I can do to fix this problem ?

I fixed it by deleting the problematic jars. I have no idea what they are for but now it compiles fine
